# how to check if Integer array which record not Exist in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
REPORTER      PARTNER  NET_WEIGHT  YEAR     COMMODITY

'Egypt',     'Canada',      '5',   '2010',   'wheat'
'Germany',     'UK',        '1',   '2011',   'wheat'
'Mexico',    'France',       '5',  '2011',   'wheat'
```

This is my table i want to create one Procedure from which we want get data which is not Exist in table whose NET_WEIGHT not Exist int able

Like this i want when i pass input as "1,12,16"

then it should return   12|null and 16|null  i have to check whose NET_WEIGHT is Not Found in Table and accordingly we should get NET_WEIGHT|null Data please  suggest me how to do this

Comment: actually i want to return whose ID not Exist in table i am passing INput as integer array  1 is found but 12 and 16 not Found to it should Give Output like 12|null and in second row 16|null @Carlos Fdev

Comment: select * from table name where NET_WEIGHT NOT IN (1,12,16);

Comment: Not like this i need which record not Exist in table Like i want 12 and 16 not Exist then i should get 12|null    16|null u got what i am trying ? @JYoThI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drop procedure if exists `tokensise`;
delimiter //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` procedure `tokensise`(`instring` varchar(255))
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
begin
declare   tempstring varchar(100);
declare   outstring  varchar(100);
declare  checkit int;
set tempstring = ltrim(rtrim(instring));
set checkit = 0;
drop table if exists occursresults;
create table occursresults(letter char(1), occurs int);
looper: while   tempstring is not null and instr(tempstring,',') > 0 do
        set outstring = substr(tempstring,1,instr(tempstring, ','));
        set tempstring = ltrim(rtrim(replace(tempstring,outstring,'')));
        set outstring = replace(outstring,',','');
        set checkit = checkit + 1;
        insert into occursresults
        select  outstring, t.NET_WEIGHT
                   from (select outstring os) d left join t on  t.NET_WEIGHT = d.os;
end while; 
    set outstring = tempstring; 
    set tempstring = ltrim(rtrim(replace(tempstring,outstring,'')));
    set outstring = replace(outstring,',','');
    set checkit = checkit + 1;
    insert into occursresults
        select  outstring, t.NET_WEIGHT
                   from (select outstring os) d left join t on  t.NET_WEIGHT = d.os;

end //
delimiter ;
```

result

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> call tokensise('1,2,5');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.38 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from occursresults;
+--------+--------+
| letter | occurs |
+--------+--------+
| 1      |      1 |
| 2      |   NULL |
| 5      |      5 |
| 5      |      5 |
+--------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: its showing Error Error Code: 1146. Table 'Parabola.t' doesn't exist

Comment: Substitute t in the select statements with whatever your table is called.

Answer (score 0):

I would use 2 tables and compare one to another - I also use NOT IN rather than NOT EXIST - this sql I use on a football database that checks if teams exist in results table but not stats table. The code below will display all rows in results where hometeam does not exist as team.stats.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    results
WHERE   hometeam NOT IN (SELECT team FROM stats)
```

Comment: I need   from one table not from another table